# Change multiple background images on key event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, keyevent

I have a circular countdown timer with background images set up. When I press 'space' the timer starts, so that works. But now I want to set up background images (there are 3 of them) so that on key press event (1,2,3), the background image would change. I don't want the onclick event!
My problem atm is that only one of the 4 functions works at the same time. Is there an easier way to achieve this or I might be just missing something foolish here?

Here is the code:

```
 document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
     if(e.keyCode == 32){
         countdown.start();
     } 

 document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
     if(e.keyCode == 49){
         $('body').css("background-image", "url(/img/image1.jpg)");
     } 

 document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
     if(e.keyCode == 50){
         $('body').css("background-image", "url(/img/image2.jpg)");
     } 

 document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
     if(e.keyCode == 51){
         $('body').css("background-image", "url(/img/image3.jpg)");
     }
```

Thanks for all the help in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're overwriting the `onkeyup` handler. You can put all the logic in a single handler. It would also be better to attach the handler using `addEventListener`, like this:

```
document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 32){
    countdown.start();
  } else if(e.keyCode == 49) {
    $('body').css("background-image", "url(/img/image1.jpg)");
  } else if (e.keyCode == 50) {
    $('body').css("background-image", "url(/img/image2.jpg)");
  } else if (e.keyCode == 51) {
     $('body').css("background-image", "url(/img/image3.jpg)");
  } 
});
```

Also note that as you're using jQuery, you can attach the events like this:

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(e){
  if (e.which == 32){
    countdown.start();
  } else if(e.which == 49) {
    $('body').css("background-image", "url(/img/image1.jpg)");
  } else if (e.which == 50) {
    $('body').css("background-image", "url(/img/image2.jpg)");
  } else if (e.which == 51) {
     $('body').css("background-image", "url(/img/image3.jpg)");
  } 
});
```

Comment: Would it be better if we use Switch cases instead of if condition?

Comment: Possibly, it depends on how many cases the OP needs to catch. I'd say the above about the limit of if/else if that I'd use.

Comment: Thank you, this works now :) I kind of tought that overlaping was the problem but was not sure.

Answer (score 1):

For better way try help of the Object .Create the Object for `keycode and images` then match the `keycode` with respected object .Place with `background-image`

```js
var image ={
"49":'"url(/img/image1.jpg)',
"50":'"url(/img/image2.jpg)',
"51":'"url(/img/image3.jpg)',
}

document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
      countdown.start();
    }
     if(Object.keys(image).includes(e.keyCode.toString())){
     $('body').css("background-image", image[e.keyCode.toString()]);
    console.log(image[e.keyCode.toString()])
    }
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `switch` statement

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(e){
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 32:
        countdown.start();
        break;
    case 49:
         $('body').css("background-image", "url(/img/image1.jpg)");
        break;
    case 50:
          $('body').css("background-image", "url(/img/image2.jpg)");
        break;
    case 51:
         $('body').css("background-image", "url(/img/image3.jpg)");
        break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not dead on sure here...

But a couple of things I noticed is that your brackets don't line up. Secondly you're being a little redundant but here goes my guess to fix it up

```
document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 32){
        countdown.start();
    } 
    if(e.keyCode == 49){
        $('body').css("background-image", "url(/img/image1.jpg)");
    } 
    if(e.keyCode == 50){
        $('body').css("background-image", "url(/img/image2.jpg)");
    } 
    if(e.keyCode == 51){
        $('body').css("background-image", "url(/img/image3.jpg)");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Rory McCrossan is probably more technically correct... My version is just a simplified version of yours